# How come the shell for my Mac can't find the postgresql command?

Tags: postgresql

I just installed PostGreSQL on my Mac. I'm sure of that since I can open up the pqsl shell just fine via clicking on

[image]

However, when I try calling `postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data` in terminal to start the database server, I get that the `postgres` command is not found.

Why is that? I feel that I might be missing something or forgetting to do something.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add postgres executable to your path. If it's in /usr/local/pgsql/bin you can add it for all users by doing the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/paths
```

To the bottom of file add a new line:

```
/usr/local/pgsql/bin
```

Comment: Oh interesting, your answer led me to what was wrong. Mac OSX lion seemed to rename `postgres` to `postgres_real`.

Comment: Did that still got the same error `-bash: psql: command not found`